# Playing a audio/wav file through URL/JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, wav

I have a audio file, which gets played when I hit the URL (says)
a.b.c.d/audio/sound1.wav
The browser plays the audio.

Now my requirement is, there is an vxml application, which will hit the URL and has to play the audio. The audio is dynamically chosen.
I have a servlet running, (vxml will hit is servlet URL to get the audio file) based or some criteria, it will select/create a audio file.
1 option is I will save the audio in some path and return the path, which vxml will later play.
However, what I want is, instead of returning the path, I will give the entire audio for it to play in the response.

A sample Code:

```
 response.setContentType("audio/x-wav");
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    byte[] audioBytes = null;       
    try {
        audioBytes  = Utils.getWavBytes("abc.wav");
        response.setContentLength(audioBytes.length);
        outStream.write(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.length);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the browser is not able to play the when i hit the url containing this code.
Note: getWavBytes() just decodes the abc.wav to byte []

Comment: You should not decode the wav file, just send it byte by byte as it is on your disk

Comment: Can you add the HTTP response where it does work and doesn't work?

Comment: Decoding the the sense, I'm reading the file and forming a bytearray. Then I'm writing the byte array to the response.

Comment: @reinard: what you mean by HTTP response in working and non working. Working scenario is when I directly play the audio in browser.

Comment: @Shelly what do you mean with directly, from the local file path or from an <audio> tag?

Comment: Directly means, I'm hitting the URL where the wav file exist. Say 172.19.10.1:5721/playAudio.wav

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you can't write directly the whole byte array in your `OutputStream`, I would suggest to use something like appache [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to copy it.

```
response.setContentLength(audioBytes.length);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioBytes);
IOUtils.copy(is, outStream);
```

or if you don't want to use a library:

```
public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    long count = copyLarge(input, output);
    if (count > 2147483647L) return -1;
    else return (int) count;
}

public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
    long count = 0L;
    for (int n = 0; -1 != (n = input.read(buffer));) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }

    return count;
}
```

You may found a working example deployed here:
https://immense-waters-1854.herokuapp.com/hello

https://github.com/x4d3/webapp-get-sound/blob/master/src/main/java/servlet/HelloServlet.java